# view tweets in share button for twitter?

Tags: twitter

I have implemented twitter share button , for sharing is working fine, it is posting.
But when I click for view all tweet, then its not showing in twitter page how many person  tweet my page.
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you give a look at the twitter documentation:[Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button/faq#count-api)

So, you must count how many times the button is clicked with javascript.

Comment: counter is increasing,but when I clicked in counter number, its going to twitter page for search, There is showing no tweets.

Comment: <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://mysite-test.com" data-text="hello" data-via="sdbwork" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>